# A program that generates lottery numbers as random numbers and outputs them by sorting them

Tags: while-loop

The error 'undefined reference to 'check' appears, but I don't know why.

```
int check(int arr[], int);

void random_no(int arr[]) // This code generates random numbers so that there is no overlap.
{
    int i, random;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE;i++)
    {
        random = (rand() % 45) + 1; //(rand()%45)-> 0~44   +1->1~45
        while(check(arr,random))
        {
            random = (rand() % 45) + 1; // If the random number that just occurred exists in array a, the random number occurs again.
        }
        arr[i] = random;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag this question with an applicable language tag, without one nobody is going to notice it.